# private variables are read later than member init list?

Tags: c++, initialization, private

I've this class:

```
class IPianoRoll : public IControl
{
private:
    int x, y;
    int w = 30 * numStep + 1;
    int h = 8 * numSemitones + 1;
    int o = 5;

public:
    IPianoRoll(IPlugBase* pPlug, int pX, int pY) : IControl(pPlug, IRECT(pX, pY, pX + o + w + o, pY + o + h + o)) {
        x = pX;
        y = pY;
    }
}
```

but it seems that private variable values are available "later" than member init list. So `o`, `w` and `h` are not init with my values, and it takes different values.

Is there a way to pre-init private variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base classes are constructed first (from left to right if there are multiple base classes), and then member variables are constructed in the order of declaration (*not* the order in any member initializer list).

However this is only the case for *non-static* member variables.  By the look of your example, `w`, `h`, and `o` are constants that apply to all instances of the class.  As such, you can just change the class to:

```
class IPianoRoll : public IControl
{
private:
    int x, y;
    static const int w = 30 * numStep + 1;
    static const int h = 8 * numSemitones + 1;
    static const int o = 5;

public:
    IPianoRoll(IPlugBase* pPlug, int pX, int pY) 
       : IControl(pPlug, IRECT(pX, pY, pX + o + w + o, pY + o + h + o)) 
       , x(pX)
       , y(pY)
    {
    }
};
```

and all will be well.  Notice that I have moved setting x and y into the member initialization list.

If you want the variables as non-static, (so that you can change them later for different instances of the class), then I would write something like:

```
class IPianoRoll : public IControl
{
private:
    int x, y;
    static const int w_default = 30 * numStep + 1;
    static const int h_default = 8 * numSemitones + 1;
    static const int o_default = 5;

    int w = w_default;
    int h = h_default;
    int o = o_default;

public:
    IPianoRoll(IPlugBase* pPlug, int pX, int pY) 
       : IControl(pPlug, IRECT(pX, pY, pX + o_default + w_default + o_default, 
                                       pY + o_default + h_default + o_default)) 
       , x(pX)
       , y(pY)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. So static variables values are "stored" before any base class/member variables?

Comment: I still think this is UB. The `IControl` base class will be initialised before the `static`s in the child class and you're passing in uninitialised `static`s into the `iControl` constructor! The compiler may well eat your cat. I'd love to be proved wrong on this though.

Comment: Yes.  The actual rules are rather complex, but basically their values are set at program startup (and constant integral values can be used as compile time constants.)

Comment: @Bathsheba: Err, no.  statics are initialized no later than entry to the first function defined in the translation unit - so they must be initialized before the constructor starts.  In this case, this doesn't mean "before the main body of the constructor" (the empty {}), it means before any part of the constructor.  Do you need chapter and verse from the standard?

Comment: I probably do ;-) What if IControl was in a different translation unit to IPianoRoll? You do agree that `IControl` is fully constructed *before* anything in `IPianoRoll` is constructed?

Comment: @Bathsheba `[basic.start.init]/2: Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization
takes place.`

Comment: @Bathsheba:  The IControl constructor being in a different TU makes no difference.  I agree that the IControl sub-object is fully constructed before any non-static member variables in IPianoRoll is constructed.  However *static* member variables are fully constructed before any IPianoRoll object even begins to be constructed.

Comment: Thanks for these clarifications. Now it's time to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The access specifier of class members is not relevant. What *is* relevant is the order they appear in the class *declaration*. Class members are initialised in *that* order.

Relying on a particular order of initialisation of class members is very dangerous since an errant refactorer could re-order them in the header file blissfully unaware that the source file relies on a particular ordering.

You should also note that the behaviour on reading an uninitialised variable is undefined.

Comment: The order here means nothing. I mean: the values are not taken within the CTOR, so I just pass not 5 as `o`, because it's not init.